# Can the word "now" be used to connect two independent clauses?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

The second definition (from the [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/now)) states: "Used, especially in conversation, to draw attention to a particular statement or point in a narrative."

Example sentence:

> I don't like Scotch. Now, if it had been Irish Whiskey you'd offered me.

Can it be used to connect two sentences together like a conjunction, as in the following example:

> I don't like Scotch, now if it had been Irish Whiskey you'd offered me.

Is that ungrammatical?

Answer (score 1):

In your example,

*I don't like Scotch. Now, if it had been Irish Whiskey you had offered me.*

this has two main issues with resultant problems.

**1. "Now" can be used as an adverb to connect two independent clauses.** This would create a similar situation to although, however, etc. In such a case you can use a period to end your first clause, or you can use a semicolon followed by your adverb +/- a comma.

*I don't like Scotch; now, if it would've been Irish Whiskey you'd offered me ...*

**2. Your second clause is not a complete sentence.** In any circumstance, it would not take a full stop. A comma can be used after "now" as above, or it could be used to introduce an *if/then* construction.

*"Can I get you a Glenlivet?"*

*"I don't like Scotch. Now if it had been an Irsh Whiskey you'd offered me, then I'd say, 'Please, on the rocks.'"*

Answer (score 0):

“Now” is indeed “used, especially in conversation, to draw attention to a particular statement or point in a narrative."

“I don't like Scotch. Now, if it had been Irish Whiskey you'd offered me.” is wrong not because of the use of “now” but because of the second full stop.

It would be better as:
“I don't like Scotch. Now, if it had been Irish Whiskey you'd offered me…” because the old full stop indicated completeness, which was not in fact present. The new ellipsis correctly indicates incompleteness… more follows, but what doesn’t really matter.

Some might go on to say it would be even better as:
“I don't like Scotch… N(n)ow, if it had been Irish Whiskey you'd offered me…” for double the same reason. Although grammatically “I don't like Scotch.” is a statement missing nothing in or of itself, in the context it is not a complete thought. In spoken English the whole expression would generally involve not a full stop and the start of a new thought, but a pause followed by an extrapolation of the original.

That way yes, “Now” can be used to connect two phrases but please note, the word “Now” is in no way necessary except as you said at first, for emphasis. In all your examples and mine, dropping “Now” would change nothing but that emphasis.

In your second example the words themselves are fine but the punctuation doesn’t fit.

“I don’t like Scotch” needs at least an ellipsis or a semi- and some might say a full colon.

With any of those and even if your original comma was enough, there should be a second comma as “… now, if it…”

Answer (score -2):

It is fine to use now in this way.

To use now as a conjunction the two clauses must be semantically linked, and specifically the latter must describe a situation which is different to the first.

In your example the 'Scotch' was offered, but you introduce a new situation by way of the hypothetical 'Irish Whiskey' so this is fine.

The usage is described with more examples in the [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/now_2):

### Now

> conjunction / us / ​ uk ​
>
> As a result of a new situation:

E.g.:

> She doesn't get out so much now that she's got the baby.
>
> How can I face him now that he knows what I've done?
>
> We're a lot better off now that Jane's started work again.
>
> She gets lonely now that the kids have all left home.
>
> Now that she's moved out, Jean seems much happier.